# How to use delimiter in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax-error

```
start.FileName = @"C:/Program Files/xyz/asd -config \"C:/Users/xyz/qwe\""
```

When I'm using the above code its giving the error at the

`closing delimiter`"\"`unexpected character`.

Comment: What actually are you trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried using apostrophe on 'C:/Users/xyz/qwe' instead of quotes?

Comment: Either you use @ or \" , but not both

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx - look especially at the parts about "verbatim" literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` symbol in front of the string specifier instructs the C# compiler to use a different escape mechanism for the string, effectively ignoring all of the standard escape sequences and rendering them as text.  The only escape sequence that is used in the alternate form of string specifier is the `""` escape sequence which inserts a single `"` character in the output.

Try your string as:

```
start.FileName = @"C:/Program Files/xyz/asd -config ""C:/Users/xyz/qwe""";
```

Or:

```
start.FileName = "C:/Program Files/xyz/asd -config \"C:/Users/xyz/qwe\"";
```

Either one works.  Or, since you're targeting a windows platform:

```
start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\xyz\asd -config ""C:\Users\xyz\qwe""";
```

Comment: Your edited question is a completely different question that has nothing to do with the string formatting problem you originally had.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

The advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write, for example, a fully qualified file name:
C#

```
@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"  // rather than "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"
```

**To include a double quotation mark in an @-quoted string, double it:**

```
@"""Ahoy!"" cried the captain." // "Ahoy!" cried the captain.
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the required quotes in the output string.

Comment: So why doesn't the OPs work? It's important to explain why the current approach didn't work - instead of simply offering a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
string line = "C:/Program Files/xyz/asd -config \"C:/Users/xyz/qwe**\"";

Console.WriteLine(line);
```